# Use perform segue into a collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

i need to pass my data into collection view with index path. 
i'm trying to use this code but i don't know why i have 2 times the result, one time it's ok and the second one is nil.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: indexPath)


}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell,
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {

        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! CollectionDetailViewController //Cast with your DestinationController
        //Now simply set the title property of vc
        secondViewController.people = person[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is enough information everything looks reasonable here, can you put the CollectionDetailViewController class here, might be doing something here that is creating duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting 2 calls to `prepare(for:sender:)` because your segue is wired from your `UICollectionViewCell`.  This will call `prepare(for:sender:)` for you, so you don't need this code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: indexPath)


}
```

Delete it, and you should be good to go.